# When is an answer Not An Answer?

Tags: discussion

This is intended to provide information for people who throw Not An Answer (NAA) flags and who might be surprised to see the canned decline reason *"flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer",* (or some other decline reason) as the response to the flag.

When should answers be flagged as Not An Answer and when should something else be done?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We see quite a lot of Not An Answer flags that shouldn't really have been thrown. The NAA flag should be thrown when the community lacks the tools to fix an issue e.g.

- The answer is asking for additional information or making a comment on the question - we can convert to a comment.
- Someone is saying I have this problem too/Did this ever get resolved/Thanks etc.
- Someone is asking a new question.

You could flag these as not an answer but you could do better

- The answer is a comment on another answer (please use *other* and let us know where it should go, use the share link).
- The answer is additional information that should be an edit to the question. We can convert to edit so using *other* and letting us know is good, you could edit the information into the question yourself and then flag *other* and request deletion.

NAA flags shouldn't be thrown when the community has the tools to fix the issue e.g.

- The answer provided is wrong.
- The answer provided doesn't  answer the question.
- The answer is phrased as a question e.g. Did you try X or Y ? Which is really a hint to the OP to do something.

You have the tools to deal with these: Downvote, leave a comment or both. If you have enough rep and you feel it necessary, you can cast a delete vote.

Additional Information:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167632/147520, [Can we have an unambiguous, official ruling on what the "not an answer" flag is for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167624/can-we-have-an-unambiguous-official-ruling-on-what-the-not-an-answer-flag-is/167625#167625)

Comment: The second bullet point in the part saying that NAAs shouldn't be thrown when the answer doesn't answer the question contradicts the FAQ:s text, where it says that answers may be removed if they are "not even a partial answer to the actual question". It'd be nice if the FAQ and the moderators could be in agreement...

Comment: @JennyD: I believe we are, it only says may not will.

Comment: Well, yes, but you seem to be saying "should not", which IMHO is a ways off from "may". At the very least it's a bit confusing for a relative newbie.

Comment: Nice post - we're working to educate and promote the proper use of not-an-answer flags. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/1629/5472 I'm a big proponent for keeping all the wrong answers online, searchable, but properly down-voted and explained as to how and why the post is incorrect. Just as many learn from a correct answer - _knowing what the answer is not_ is equally beneficial to learning.

Comment: Great. So don't use NAA if the answer doesn't answer the question (?!)

Comment: It seems to me the confusion is the difference between "is a wrong answer" (which shouldn't be NAA) and "is not even a wrong answer", which is what I think should be NAA.

Comment: @Iain I find that when a comment is an answer, many users tend to steal the answer in that comment and post it as their own answer.

Comment: @cybermonkey [That's entirely acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a/117268#117268)

Comment: What is recommended when the "answer" does not even try to address the question? I am asking because I flagged NAA an answer telling how to list KBs, because the question was about to uninstall KBs. My flag was "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Comment: @Law29 A downvote.

Comment: @Law29 That's just a wrong answer - downvote it.

Comment: OK, so "Not an answer" should not be used to flag posts which are not answers to the question. That's illogical, but no matter.