# Disagree with a declined flag

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this answer as NAA](https://serverfault.com/a/715492/218888).
The reasoning behind it being that it is clearly an attempted comment on the answer [right below it](https://serverfault.com/a/672904/218888).
This flag has since been rejected for `flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer`.

Without the answer below it, the first answer is simply gibberish unrelated to the question.

Should I flag this differently? Should I in stead have down-voted it?
The information is clearly useful, simply miss-placed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you are right, I've misinterpreted this, and your flag was correct.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for being a pain in the rear end :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that throwing a NAA flag was the correct thing to do here, I would have declined it too.

Some time ago I wrote a [Q&A about the NAA flag](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and it's (mis)use, it is still relevant and is applicable here.

I think you could have done better. In particular you could have flagged Other and left information to the effect that it should be a comment, with a link to the answer it should be a comment to.

Better still would be to edit it into the relevant answer then flag other and request deleting with an explanation of why and what you did.

Comment: For the better still: I _can't_ turn questions into comments with an edit. And I wasn't 100℅ sure if the comment was valid.

Comment: No, but you can read what I said :) You _can_ edit the text/meaning of the comment into the relevant answer and then flag the comment for deletion explaining why ...

Comment: I did read that part. That's why I added the part about not being sure if the comment was valid :P