# Why was this flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging, flag

This is about a particular flag about this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/425438/create-and-use-intermediate-certificate-authority-on-windows-server-2012/440581#440581) that got declined:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxErhxEbQcA&feature=plcp is a good video. Start at ep 11 and work your way through the SSL bits.

The flag I raised was "not an answer" *("This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment**, another question, or deleted altogether.)*

The flag got declined with the following reason: *"flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"*

I was not meant to say the answer was inaccurate or wrong. I flagged it as a non-answer because it was a link to a video without any context. It's a low-quality answer that rather should have been stated as a comment.

The Help section is quite clear about that.

> **Provide context for links**
>
> Links to external resources are encouraged, but **please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.**

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Clarifying, the reason why a link to a video is not valid, is that even though it answers the question for the user now, that link/video may not work in X period of time from now.  An answer should be self-contained on this site and not dependent on another external site as the internet is quite fluid and StackExchange (and friends), needs to keep self-contained to protect the integrity of questions and solutions

Answer (score 9):

The flag declination was absolutely appropriate.

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether

That is the flag reason you chose, and it's incorrect. The answer *does* attempt to answer the question. It may not be a high-quality answer, but it is an answer.

Flags should not be used to indicate low-quality and/or incorrect answers. That's what the downvote arrow is for.

Seriously, though, it's just a flag. Don't worry about it.

Comment: ...and now that it's been voted down to -3, it's now accepting delete votes from the community... if there's anyone else around who has that priv.