# Why does this count as a valid answer?

Tags: support, flagging, low-quality

I came across a [question](https://serverfault.com/q/550276/214507) asking the following:

> Recently, I have encountered a problem of limiting Internet Access to specific programs. Could anybody recommend a good way of doing that, without using any particular software?

One of the [answers](https://serverfault.com/a/730989/214507) says:

> use "nointernet" instead of "no-internet". For whatever reason Ubuntu 14.04 can't handle the dash when you try to use sg or chgrp (it prompts for a password, then fails).

Since there is no connection between question and answer, I flagged this as not an answer. Obviously this was meant as a comment on an [earlier answer](https://serverfault.com/a/550278/214507).

The flag was declined. Why?

Comment: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hadn't had a coffee yet ...

In such cases, you can help by making the situation more obvious. Leave a comment below the answer or use the "other" flag reason and explain there.

Comment: What Sven said.  Okay, I'm not a mod, but I've noticed that my flags are more likely to be accepted if I explain why I'm flagging them rather than use the canned reasons.  (For example:  "It looks like the user has two accounts with the same name and has answered the question twice with identical wording.  Answers have one upvote each.  Seems hinky.")

Comment: +1 what Sven said, also what Katherine said.  Our mods are called upon to be experts on local community ethics and etiquette; lovely as they are, expecting them also to be experts on every aspect of sysadmin is a little unfair (though no doubt they all have substantial expertise in some fields of that, too).  **When you flag, make it as easy as possible for them to follow what you're thinking, and why!**  Also, buy them a coffee.