# your post was converted to a comment

Tags: discussion

a user asked a question and set bounty:

[Apache tries to access wsgi-rest parameters in DocumentRoot (AH01797) - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/731739/apache-tries-to-access-wsgi-rest-parameters-in-documentroot-ah01797)

I posted my answered it (in hope to get bounty), yet few moments later, I noticed my answer was converted into comment for whatever reason...

I even got upvote (answer was useful) from another user...

Can my question converted back from comment into answer?

---

I actually re-read question and I tried to answer it differently)

---

@Sven, @Shog9 and whoever else thought my answer was incorrect, per @x539 (OP) I'll quote:

> What actually helped was Updating the access-control syntax. As
>   suggested not in this post but in the comment of @alexus.

**muahahaha!** *victory dance*))

Comment: A moderator can undelete your answer, but normal users cannot.

Comment: It's almost certainly a duplicate too but it's almost certainly too difficult to find.

Comment: I did this and I've to say: What @shog9 said. If the question where about Apache 2.4, I  likely would have let it stand, but even then I would consider this an absolute borderline case of a useful answer.

Comment: Whatever [happened to downvotes](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) ? I guess that like dupes they're a waste of time and we should do away with them?

Comment: @iain, exactly) I actually even got upvote on my answer, so someone else though it was useful as well.

Comment: @Sven Thank your comment. I saw an error from 2.4, and syntax of 2.2, so I immediately saw that as a possible cause of an issue, so I post an answer and in addition I provided link with greater details.

Comment: @Sven (or I dont know if someone else can do it) - Do you mind undoing your conversion? deleting comment and un-deleting my answer? Thank you! (oh and you're welcome to down vote my answer if you don't think it's useful)

Comment: Fitting gif based on avatar: http://gph.is/11RIbqM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A moderator would have to undelete it, as normal users can't cast undelete votes on answers deleted by mods.  For what it's worth, I agree with you that it is an answer to the question.

Comment: It looks like a comment to me.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Q: `Why is Apache trying to access something in the DocumentRoot?` A: [because] `your access control syntax written for httpd 2.2`.  That's an answer.  A wrong answer, and not a very good answer, but an answer, nonetheless.  Back when I bothered to flag things much at all, I was reminded on a semi-regular basis that a wrong answer or a bad answer is not the same thing as not-an-answer.

Comment: OK, you've got a point there.

Comment: https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Answer (score 4):

The system has this to say about comments

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Your comment is not asking for more information or suggesting improvements - it's not a comment.

Your answer should be undeleted and the comment made from it removed.

Normal voting should determine it's value to the community. That is the correct tool for this job.

---

[image: Oh dear how sad is that :(]

I fail to see how wanting to downvote a bad answer demonstrates *greatly-lowered* standards.

I'm sorry that your previous statements got in the way of a good argument but facts and all.

Comment: Some of the comments on the deleted answer (like Shog's above) make me want to turn this Internet right around.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard Careful, now... sounds like you're disagreeing with someone there.  Even worse, it could be taken as agreeing with someone else. Someone could take such a thing personally, you know.

Comment: @Iain "Your **comment** is not asking for more information or suggesting improvements - it's not a comment." - then, any random turn or phrase is an answer? (Q. what's the capital of Norway? A. It's not Paris!) - I flagged the "Answer" as a comment  - there was a specific question that had nothing whatsoever to do with Apache syntax - and then a comment about Apache syntax with no explanation as to why it was being pointed out. the comment has since been edited to make it look a little less like a total Red Herring.

Comment: @Rob-d That's the SE stance, yeah.  "Not Paris!" "Purple?" and "Washington D.C." all count as answers to the question of what Norway's capital is.  Before he deleted it, someone posted an answer with [SE's stance on what constitutes an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).  Like it says, think of them as apples.  A rotted-out apple serving as bug food is still an apple.

Comment: @josh that's mostly correct yes NAA is a blunt instrument. I wrote [this Q&A](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/) based on some mSE posts [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/when-to-use-naa-and-when-to-flag-mod-other/199460#199460),[2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167632/147520) to explain it. SE has some odd definitions for example an unanswered question may have one or more answers non of which have an upvote. Alexus' answer was an answer. It may have been wrong or an answer to a different question but it's still an answer and should be acted upon appropriately.

Comment: I'm actually the person who upvoted the since-deleted answer.  I appreciate that he was backing up Sven.  That doesn't make me less exasperated with the comment thread that followed.  (As for whether the comment/answer is an answer or not, I think the OP should repost it as one, expanding it as suggested here to make sure we all realize it's an answer, and have done with it.)

Comment: @Iain I actually still think that my answer was correct answer, but again I'd expect OP to test any changes in testing environment before promoting any changes into live environment. Since Sven is MIA, I went ahead and answer question again, but slightly different) Thanks to KatherineVillyard for UV!

Comment: @alexus I see you got your bounty! Congratulations! I'm really glad you reposted an expanded version of your answer.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard at the end of the day, I'm the real winner here) and that's because I learned new things) Thanks to everyone all around!

Comment: @alexus - I'm glad you learned something, unfortunately it had nothing to do with Apache syntax, as the same error was in the OP's 2.2 config, try figuring that one out.

Comment: @Rob-d Many OPs don't really know. Without seeing the OPs configs written in blood I'd take what they say with a pinch of salt.