# Why was this NAA flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flagging

On the question [How do I force sync the time on Windows Workstation or Server?](https://serverfault.com/q/294787/205065) this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/859669/205065) was posted.  It clearly does not attempt to answer the question, so I flagged it NAA. My flag was declined with

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

**Why was this flag declined?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is an answer Not An Answer?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5316/when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I've read the duplicate question. Its answer says *"You could flag these as not an answer but you could do better[:] The answer is a comment on another answer (please use other and let us know where it should go, use the share link)."* **Is this why the flag was declined?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was the mod who declined this flag.  I tend to set a pretty high bar for accepting NAA flags, because I don't want to slam the door in someone's face for *trying* to answer a question, especially when here on ServerFault, we often try to answer the question people are *really* asking.

Digging deeper into the context of the (large and annoyingly repetitious) answers on that question, I can see now that the flagged answer was an attempt to reply to another answer, rather than being a standalone answer on its own.  It would help if you could make that clear, as per the answer on the (previously-dupe) question.

I've now fixed up the situation, by moving the flagged answer to a comment on the other answer it appears to be a response to.  Sorry for the sting of a declined flag, but I don't think I can fix that.  I regret my error, and will attempt to do better in the future.

Comment: I am grateful for your response. I apologize for not providing you sufficient context for my flag. I learned through asking about this that I need to do that in a case like this. Thank you for giving of your time to moderate and I want you to know *the fact you responded and addressed this has restored my faith in moderation of SF. Thanks for that.*

Comment: Seriously, you two, whatever will happen to the Serverfault we know and "love", if everyone is being all polite and reasonable like this?

Comment: Indeed.  In penance, I will downvote 50 poor questions and leave at least three "You have no idea what you're doing" comments.